# Wanna save text_format custom form in comment

Tags: ajax, comments, wysiwyg, chaos-tool-suite

I'm using a custom form in CTools Modal to alter comment.

```
$form['subject'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('Title'),
   '#default_value' => $comment->subject,
);  
$form['comment_body'] = array(
   '#type' => 'text_format',
   '#default_value' => $comment->comment_body['und'][0]['value']
);
```

All is good. I get my comment title and my comment body which is pushed in ckeditor field. My submit :

```
$comment = comment_load($form_state['values']['cid']);
$comment->comment_body['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['comment_body']['und'][0]['value'];
$comment->subject = $form_state['values']['title'];

comment_submit($comment);
comment_save($comment);
```

The subject is goodly saved from my form but for the body, it save an empty value.

Ps: when I change `text_format` for `textfield`, it work.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the format:

```
$comment->comment_body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format'] = $form_state['values']['comment_body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format'];
```

Comment: Even with this line, it save me an empty value.
Maybe something to know, when in my validate I put a `form_set_error` in `$form_state['values']['comment_body'] == ''` it doesn't pass even if i let the comment input form empty.

Comment: And you've confirmed that the form state array contains the elements you're trying to access?

Comment: Haha, your comment gave me an illumination : it was `$form_state['values']['comment_body']['value']` missed this final _value_ so, in the submit it looks like : `$comment->comment_body['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['comment_body']['value'];` (same thing for format). Thanks you @Clive